# CSS3 filter drop-shadow radius on retina vs non-retina

Tags: css, svg, css-filters

The drop-shadow filter on Chrome has a smaller blur radius on retina than on non-retina. There doesn't seem to be a problem with safari.

CSS:

```
.logo-head svg {
  fill: #FFF;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 12px 24px #000);
     -moz-filter: drop-shadow(0 12px 24px #000);
          filter: drop-shadow(0 12px 24px #000);
}
```

Retina Display:

[image]

Non Retina Display:

[image]

Does anyone have a fix for this? All I get in Google is a fix for another SVG issue, where the actual SVG gets blurred because of the filter.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably retina's greater pixel ratio. Try a media query and then double the values for retina.

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
    /* RETINA, YOU'RE SO SPECIAL */
}
```